# Include framework headers using double quotes (instead of angular brackets)

Tags: ios, frameworks

Currently I am working on refactoring of large project. Here I have to divide as modules with available codebase. And it should be framework Type.

As separate folder and separate framework successfully done. While including separate folder of source file doesn't make any problem. But for including framework I have to change all import statements in whole project.

Ex.

```
#import "APIConnection.h"
```

after including should be,

```
#import <Framework/APIConnection.h>
```

Problem: Please suggest me the solution where I can include framework and import it's header files using double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For include Header directly, Compiler should know will to find it. So you should add the header directory into the Header Search Path.

Framework is just a special Folder, The headers is put in a Header directory inside the framework.

After I tested, Xcode recursive path do not work with frameworks. Also directly importing framework headers without Framework name prefix is unrecommend. Especially for system frameworks. As it is hard to distinguish between Project Headers and Frameworks Headers.

For your custom framework, if you like, you can set the framework project root dir as Recursive Header search Path.

### Example:

first Path include All Headers in your project.
second Path contains Frameworks, but recursive is not work.
so need to specify explicitly in third Path.

[image]

And then You can directly import `UIView.h` Or `UIKit.h`
(Note the completion may not work. but the compile success)

[image]

Comment: @AlokRao Yes, Framework is Just a special Folder, say your Framework path is /path/to/framework.framework. then you can add /path/to/framework.framework/Headers/ into your Header search path. Or more easily, Xcode support recursive header search path,so just set root path and choose recursive.

Comment: I tried with my framework. It was not recognising the files. Then I tried with SpriteKit Framework. Problem persisted.

Comment: It did not work with System Libraries. Have you tried above example in blank project ? But it worked with my custom framework.. Ty

Comment: @AlokRao In fact, You can see all include dirs in the compile Log. The -I flag shows your custom include path. If your header file doesn't in these directory, the compile complains file not found and you need to add it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to set `CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER` settings to `NO` for build setting of targets and for pods

In the `Podfile` add:

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config| 
      config.build_settings['CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```